# Как открыть документ онлайн?

Tags: php

Пишу сайт на php и понадобился просмотр документов онлайн. Желательно как в mail.ru, чтобы открывались. Можете подсказать в каком направлении искать?

Comment: в каком формате?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/tiktokcoach/blog/223179/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороший вопрос... Если из общей информации, то смотря какие документы. Есть 
XML - парсеры, там скрипт 1 на всё, для записи в массив! А дальше цикл foreach чтоб раскидать на страницу из массива.
Если текстовые документы, то есть функции для чтения из файлов:

$file = filegetcontens(); - для построчного чтения, 
$file = file(); - для чтения в массив. 
Есть ещё вариант с fopen(); но все функции уже есть в PHP которые всё сделают за нас: распарсят и поместят в строку, массив и т.д.

**Ссылки на документацию по этим темам:**

```
**XML:** https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.xml.php
**file():** https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php
**filegetcontens():** https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но нужно просматривать документы в формате doc и docx

Comment: Благодарю за интересный вопрос. Я загуглил эту тему... с такими документами .doc и docx - тоже базовая работа с файлами и главное XML... На этом всё состоит. Вот ссылка для начала: https://habr.com/ru/post/138666/

Гугл запрос: записать в переменную php из .docx